# C++ How MergeSort returns nothing but works fine?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, mergesort

This is the implementation of merge sort below. However, I don't understand how this code even works. We don't use pointers and nothing is  returned in `main()`. So, how does it manipulate `myarray`? Can anyone explain?

**Here is the code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) {
  int i = l;
  int j = m + 1;
  int k = l;

  /* create temp array */
  int temp[5];

  while (i <= m && j <= r) {
    if (arr[i] <= arr[j]) {
      temp[k] = arr[i];
      i++;
      k++;
    } else {
      temp[k] = arr[j];
      j++;
      k++;
    }
  }

  /* Copy the remaining elements of first half, if there are any */
  while (i <= m) {
    temp[k] = arr[i];
    i++;
    k++;
  }

  /* Copy the remaining elements of second half, if there are any */
  while (j <= r) {
    temp[k] = arr[j];
    j++;
    k++;
  }

  /* Copy the temp array to original array */
  for (int p = l; p <= r; p++) {
    arr[p] = temp[p];
  }
}
```

**mergeSort function:**

```
/* l is for left index and r is right index of the 
   sub-array of arr to be sorted */
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) {
  if (l < r) {
    // find midpoint
    int m = (l + r) / 2;

    // recursive mergesort first and second halves 
    mergeSort(arr, l, m);
    mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);

    // merge
    merge(arr, l, m, r);
  }
}
```

**Main function:**

```
int main() {
  int myarray[5];
  //int arr_size = sizeof(myarray)/sizeof(myarray[0]);
  int arr_size = 5;

  cout << "Enter 5 integers in any order: " << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cin >> myarray[i];
  }
  cout << "Before Sorting" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << myarray[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
  mergeSort(myarray, 0, (arr_size - 1)); // mergesort(arr,left,right) called

  cout << "After Sorting" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << myarray[i] << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: An array passed as an argument is implicitly a pointer.

Comment: *We dont use pointers* -- This: `void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)` is exactly the same as this: `void merge(int* arr, int l, int m, int r)`

Comment: Fair question, but definitely showing a lack of research.  A quick web search about passing arrays as function parameters results in abundant explanations, and is always discussed in even the most basic tutorials on the matter.  e.g.:  [C++ Passing Arrays to Functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This program uses two obscure features of C++ that were acquired from C for backwards compatibility.

1. [Array-to-pointer decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay). In most contexts, mentioning an array name is actually a shorthand of taking the address of the array's first element. Thus, `mergeSort(myarray, ...)` is the same as `mergeSort(&myarray[0], ...)`.
2. [Function parameter type adjustments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Parameter_list). You cannot pass an array to a function by value, so what does `void mergeSort(int arr[], ...)` ever mean? Just like in C, a function parameter of type *array-of-something* gets adjusted to *pointer-to-something*. So this function is exactly the same as `void mergeSort(int* arr, ...)`

So this program does use pointers after all, they are just thinly veiled.

The features mentioned above are essential for dealing with C-style arrays. C++ has alternatives to C-style arrays, namely `std::array` and `std::vector`, which are usually recommended in most cases. Note, in order to get the same behaviour as in your program one usually passes these containers *by reference*.

Comment: I think for completeness references should be mentioned as well, especially that one would pass the STL containers by reference (not pointer) to get the same behavior as in OPs code.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation of `mergeSort()` only uses C arrays, not C++ vectors or other containers.

C arrays are always passed by reference, ie: calling `mergeSort(myarray, 0, (arr_size - 1))` actually passes a pointer to the first element of `myarray` to the function. The function definition `void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)` is actually equivalent to `void mergeSort(int *arr, int l, int r)`

The implementation has multiple problems:

- it can only sort arrays of up to 5 elements because the `temp` array in the `merge` function is defined with a hard coded length of `5`: `int temp[5];`
- it does not *work fine*, it actually has undefined behavior and seems to work on a specific set of values. The final loop copying values from `temp` back to the array is bogus: `arr[p] = temp[p];` should be changed to `arr[p] = temp[p - l];`
- less important, there is a classic bug here: `int m = (l + r) / 2;` this may cause an arithmetic overflow for large arrays. The correct expression is `int m = l + (r - l) / 2;` and all index variables should have type `size_t` instead of `int`.